# this method will not work when called in another class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

this peice of code initialises X as a new formatter variable.

```
 private Formatter X;
     public void Create() {
                    try{
                        X = new Formatter("users.txt");
                        X.format("%1$20s %2$20s %3$20s %4$20s %5$20s %6$20s %7$20s %8$20s %9$20s \n","Firstname","Lastname","Password","ID","Addressln1","Addressln2","Addressln3","EstimatedValue","Tax Owed");
                        System.out.println("Due to there not being any users file present one has been created.");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("There is a users file present so i will not create another one.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the piece of code i am having trouble with , at the X.format bit , it keeps giving me a null pointer error and i have tried everything to fix it.

```
public void WriteToFilecmd(){
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter your First name");
                String Fname = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter your Last name");
                String Lname = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter your Password");
                String Password = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter your user ID");
                String ID = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter the first address line of your Property");
                String addressln1 = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter the second address line of your Property");
                String addressln2 = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter the third address line of your Property");
                String addressln3 = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter the properties estimated market value");
                String EstimatedPropertyValue = input.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter your tax owed");
                String Taxowed = input.next();
                input.close();
                X.format("%1$20s %2$20s %3$20s %4$20s %5$20s %6$20s %7$20s %8$20s %9$20s \n",Fname,Lname,Password,ID,addressln1,addressln2,addressln3,EstimatedPropertyValue,Taxowed);


    }
```

Comment: Please attach your stacktrace

Comment: Where do you assign to - or even define - `X`? Certainly not in this code. It kinda boils down to this.

Comment: Show us how - and when - you create X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NullPointerException` on the line

```
X.format("%1$20s %2$20s %3$20s %4$20s %5$20s %6$20s %7$20s %8$20s %9$20s \n",Fname,Lname,Password,ID,addressln1,addressln2,addressln3,EstimatedPropertyValue,Taxowed);
```

means either that `X` itself is null, or the method throws it. Normally, Java foundation classes handle `null` arguments very well (and `Scanner#next()` does not return null anyways) and don't contain bugs, so `X` is most likely `null` at the moment it's being used.

This could happen if your `create` method catches an exception (see the console output), you overwrite `X` later or if you don't call the `create` method at all or you call it too late.

Also note that pokemon exception handling ("gotta catch them all", `catch(Exception e)`) is a bad practice. Catch what you can handle, not what you can catch.

Comment: thanks i got rid of the exception handling bit and it worked perfect thank you so much ive spent so much time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Pay close attention to this line:

```
X.format("%1$20s %2$20s %3$20s %4$20s %5$20s %6$20s %7$20s %8$20s %9$20s \n",Fname,Lname,Password,ID,addressln1,addressln2,addressln3,EstimatedPropertyValue,Taxowed);
```

Where does the variable `X` come from?  If it *is* defined at a level higher than this method (likely class), then the value in it is `null`, and you can't dereference null.

Comment: x is a new formatter for a text file called users.txt

Comment: `x` is definitely defined. Otherwise, you'd get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure X (whatever it is) has been initialized.

Example of this if,
you don't know what it means:

```
Scanner scanner; // not initialized
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // initialized
```

You dont have to initialize the variable in the declaration though. This will initialize the variable too:

```
Scanner scanner; // not initialized
scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // good job you init'd it!
```

If you don't set the variable using "new", you'll get the nullpointerexception.
Make sure you do this before you call WriteToFilecmd.

Obviously, don't set your x variable to "new Scanner(System.in)", 
call the constructor of X's type.

Comment: More formally, your lines are "declared" and "declared and initialized".  But you're pretty much spot on.

Comment: @Makoto pretty much spot on? Ill take it!